# In C# can I write a generic function to return null or the value as a string?

Tags: c#, generics, nullable

Basically I want the following generic function:

```
public string StringOrNull<T> (T value)
{
    if (value != null)
    {
       return value.ToString();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I know I could use a constraint such as where T: class, but T can be a primitive type, Nullable<>, or a class. Is there a generic way to do this?

**Edit**

Turns out I jumped the gun. This actually works just fine as this sample shows:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 7;
            Nullable<int> n_i = 7;
            Nullable<int> n_i_asNull = null;
            String foo = "foo";
            String bar = null;


            Console.WriteLine(StringOrNull(i));
            Console.WriteLine(StringOrNull(n_i));
            Console.WriteLine(StringOrNull(n_i_asNull));
            Console.WriteLine(StringOrNull(foo));
            Console.WriteLine(StringOrNull(bar));


        }

        static private string StringOrNull<T>(T value)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                return value.ToString();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem? It seems to compile for me.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I didn't think I could check a primitive type against null. Maybe I was mistaken.

Comment: @grieve: if you'd tried it you'd have found it worked. If you pass in a value type then it will box it and then check if it is null (which it won't be of course) and then return its string.

Comment: @Chris: My bad. I had two levels of indirection, and was getting confused by the error. This does work with primitive and nullables types just fine.

Comment: Just as a reminder to myself: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fun one:

```
public static class ExtensionFunctions{
    public static string ToStringOrNull( this object target ) {
        return target != null ? target.ToString() : null;
    }
}
```

The cool part? This will work:

```
( (string) null ).ToStringOrNull();
```

So will this:

```
 5.ToStringOrNull();
```

Extension functions are pretty awesome... they even work on null objects!

If you pass a primitive type, it will automatically be [boxed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx), so you don't need to worry about the `null` comparison. Since boxing occurs automatically, you can even explicitly compare an `int` to `null` without an error, but the result will always be `false` (and you'll probably get a compiler warning telling you so).

Comment: Accepted for the new knowledge of ExtensionFunctions, and reminding me about boxing. I should have remembered that. :)

Answer (score 4):

[default Keyword in Generic Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

In generic classes and methods, one issue that arises is how to assign a default value to a parameterized type T when you do not know the following in advance:

Whether T will be a reference type or a value type.

If T is a value type, whether it will be a numeric value or a struct.

Comment: The method doesn't return `T`. It returns a `string`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) keyword to return the default of T:

```
public string StringOrNull<T> (T value)
{
    .....

    return default(T).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why generic?

```
public string StringOrNull (object value)
{
    if (value != null){
       return value.ToString();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Do primitives inherit from object?

Comment: @grieve - See my answer: primitives (or value types) are automatically boxed. They do not inherit from object, but they are automatically wrapped in an object thus allowing the comparison to null, etc.